# Hibernate: Multiple associations to the same class

Tags: hibernate, associations

I need to associate an entity with two lists of other entities – both lists containing entities of the same type.  It looks something like this:

```
@Entity
public class Course {
    private List<Test> preTests;
    @OneToMany(cascade= javax.persistence.CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = “course”)
    @OrderBy("testNumber")
    public List< Test > getPreTests() {
        return preTests;
    }

    public void setPreTests(List< Test > preTests) {
        this. preTests = preTests;
    }

    private List<Test> postTests;
    @OneToMany(cascade= javax.persistence.CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = “course”)
    @OrderBy("testNumber")
    public List< Test > getPostTests() {
        return postTests;
    }

    public void setPostTests(List< Test > postTests) {
        this. postTests = postTests;
    }
}
```

Now, I haven’t even bothered to try this *per se* because it seems obvious that Hibernate would have no way to distinguish which `Tests` go into `preTests` and which into `postTests`.  Correct me if I’m wrong, but the only information it has to work with are the foreign keys in the `Test` table pointing to the `Course` record, and both the pre- and post-Tests will point at the same `Course`.
My next thought was to create explicit `PreTest` and `PostTest` subclasses of `Test`, and have one `List<PreTest>` and one `List<PostTest>`, but that leads to the infamous “mappedBy reference an unknown target entity property: course” problem, which the folks at Hibernate claim – for reasons that strike me as fussy – is by-design and therefore not likely to go away.

My current thought is to use separate join tables to hold the two associations.  I see no reason why that shouldn’t work.  It also suits my desire to keep all explicit SQL (or even HQL) out of the entity definitions, and to resist the coercion to create weird composite keys or otherwise write code that reflects only the quirks of my persistence framework rather than my object design.

Still, before I commit myself to that course, I’m asking whether any of you has a cleaner solution or knows of flaws in my reasoning here.

Thanks in advance.

Michael

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this is a really good idea or not but you could include a

```
@org.hibernate.annotations.Where
```

annotation on your association mapping and use a discriminator column on your Test table so that you can tell a Pre from a Post test when loading the Test instances.

Comment: I gave you an upvote because it's certainly a reasonable answer, but it falls under my desire to keep actual SQL/HQL out of things, so I prefer my solution, even at the expense of an extra couple of tables and mildly less efficient queries.

Answer (score 1):

One option is the [Table per class hierarchy](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html/inheritance.html#inheritance-tableperclass) method of inheritance mapping, which it sounds like you started doing, but didn't go all the way with.

Another option is, as otherwise mentioned, using the [@Where annotation](http://docs.jboss.org/ejb3/app-server/HibernateAnnotations/reference/en/html_single/index.html).

A third option, which I often use for similar cases, is to map a single collection for all Tests related to the Course, and then add helper methods to return just the desired subsets when you want to work with pre or post tests. Example code:

```
    @Entity
    public class Course {

    private List<Text> tests;

    @OneToMany(cascade= javax.persistence.CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = “course”)
    @OrderBy("testNumber")
    public List< Test > getTests() {
        return tests;
    }

    public List< Test > getPreTests() {
        List<Test> preTests = new ArrayList<Test>();
        for (Test test : preTests) {
           if (test.isPreTest()) {
               preTests.add(test);
           }
        }
        return preTests;
    }


    public List< Test > getPostTests() {
        List<Test> postTests = new ArrayList<Test>();
        for (Test test : postTests) {
           if (test.isPostTest()) {
               postTests.add(test);
           }
        }
        return postTests;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, Stevi, but I'm not sure where I dropped off the "Table per class hierarchy" method -- that's how I set the inheritance up, but I still got the "unknown target entity property" error.  Unless perhaps you're suggesting that I either move the 'course' field down into the child classes, or otherwise fiddle with the class hierarchy to fake Hibernate out?  The other two suggestions are reasonable, but inelegant -- IMO slightly less elegant than the one I suggested.

Comment: I'm not sure based on what I see in your question why you'd be getting "unknown target entity property" so I can't speak to that. I've added example code for the third option. No, it's not the most elegant of solutions, but I tend to be pretty pragmatic in my approach to dealing with Hibernate.